# Facebook graph api for getting friendlist

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook graph api for fetching friendslist using access token:
But i am only able to get total no of friends but not their list. Please check my code and please modified it. Thanks in advance.

$access_token = 'CAACEdEose0cBAFNQnu750MpGvA1EPwPVB7Sx7Q6JlYv8iCHqO9ETJ1jiB8l1SSLO3ZBNUMgiZBBOzHNZCNUzYOO8lUA7e9Ch2F9h9cTVQliWEbi0hcKJnovepTj1rF4g1zFXNvV2PCeSqoTNAiEecf5DNyPVO5C1Lvy6TWQ6ZBY02ADmxgZBUMGmeykpPf8wzp............';

$userdetails = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/friends?fields=ids,name&access_token=".$access_token);
print_r($userdetails);
?>

output:
{"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":101}}

Answer (score 0):

Since April 2014 you can only get the friends who authorized your App too for privacy reasons, check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog